# Auto-generate alert rules in Prometheus in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, alert, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I set up a Prometheus instance using the [Prometheus Community Helm Chart](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) in Kubernetes. Whenever a persistent volume is 70% full I get an alert via Slack. To achieve this I have added some code to the values file of the helm chart (an example is seen below).
The whole thing works quite well, but currently, I need to add a new alert for each new persistent volume.

Is there a quicker way to auto-generate these rules (or define them using variables)? The relevant part of my values files can be seen below.

```
additionalPrometheusRulesMap:
    rule-name:
     groups:
     - name: storage
       rules:
        - alert: grafanaStorageAt70%
          expr: ( sum(kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{job="kubelet", namespace="kube-logging", persistentvolumeclaim="prom-grafana"}) 
                - sum(kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes{job="kubelet", namespace="kube-logging", persistentvolumeclaim="prom-grafana"})) 
                / sum(kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{job="kubelet", namespace="kube-logging", persistentvolumeclaim="prom-grafana"}) > 0.7
          for: 15m
          labels:
            severity: warning
          annotations:
            summary: The Storage of Grafana is 70% full. Maybe increase the storage size?
        
        - alert: lokiStorageAt70%
          expr: ( sum(kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{job="kubelet", namespace="kube-logging", persistentvolumeclaim="storage-loki-0"}) 
                - sum(kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes{job="kubelet", namespace="kube-logging", persistentvolumeclaim="storage-loki-0"})) 
                / sum(kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{job="kubelet", namespace="kube-logging", persistentvolumeclaim="storage-loki-0"})> 0.7
          for: 15m
          labels:
            severity: warning
          annotations:
            summary: The Storage of Loki is 70% full. Maybe increase the storage size?
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are able to express the extent of volumes to alert on through PromQL wildcards, you can have a single rule for all volumes in question.

Prometheus is actually quite smart about doing arithmetic operations on values with matching value labels, even when you use wildcards.

E.g., a rule to cover all instances of loki persistent volumes (i.e. not just the `-0`) would look like this:

```
additionalPrometheusRulesMap:
    rule-name:
     groups:
     - name: storage
       rules:
        - alert: lokiStorageAt70%
          expr: ( sum(kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{job="kubelet", namespace="kube-logging", persistentvolumeclaim=~"storage-loki-.+"}) 
                - sum(kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes{job="kubelet", namespace="kube-logging", persistentvolumeclaim=~"storage-loki-.+"})) 
                / sum(kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{job="kubelet", namespace="kube-logging", persistentvolumeclaim=~"storage-loki-.+"})> 0.7
          for: 15m
          labels:
            severity: warning
          annotations:
            summary: The Storage of Loki is 70% full. Maybe increase the storage size?
```

This being just an example, you can of course make the wildcard even wilder to cover more of the volumes you want to alert on.